# Which matrices generate the same lattices?

Tags: matrices, integer-lattices

Given are the following matrices:

$A_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 7 &9 \\ 
3 & 5 &3 \\ 
1 &2  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$ , $A_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}
10 & 9 &6 \\ 
11 & 7 &2 \\ 
5 &3  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$ , $A_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}
14 & 11 &4 \\ 
13 & 18 &6 \\ 
-18 &-4  &-2 
\end{bmatrix}$ , $A_{4}=\begin{bmatrix}
11 & 13 &2 \\ 
11 & 21 &3 \\ 
-13 &-5  &-1 
\end{bmatrix}$

Which of them generate the same lattices? The lattices are generated by the rows of the basis matrices.

I calculated the determinants of the matrices and got $det\left | A_{1} \right |=det\left | A_{4} \right |=6$ and $det\left | A_{2} \right |=det\left | A_{3} \right |=18$. Is it a correct approach to solve the exercise? Do i have to do something more? 
Can anyone help me with this problem, please?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If two matrices do not have the same determinant, then they do not generate the same lattice.  But if they have the same determinant, they still might generate different lattices.  You need to check that the two matrices have the same [Hermite normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form).

Comment: Some more detail: two matrices $A$ and $B$ generate the same lattice if the set of integer linear combinations of the rows of $A$ equals the set of integer linear combinations of the rows of $B.$  This will be the case if there is an integer matrix $U$ with determinant $\pm1$ such that $UA=B.$  This means that you can check that $BA^{-1}$ is an integer matrix with determinant $\pm1.$  The Hermite normal form is another way to go: it is a canonical form shared by all integer matrices related to each other by such unimodular transformations $U.$

Comment: Thank you very much for the information!